# Помогите выбрать key-value БД

Tags: база-данных

Нужна простая БД , все данные будут лежать в RAM и хранить их ненадо, потеря всей Бд не критична, можно развернуть по новой , Бд будет типа: `"ключ-значение1-значение2-значение3"`, значения цифровые, главное чтобы можно было делать выборку по диапазону , например : найти все ключи где `значение1` в диапазоне от 100 до 150 и `значение2` в диапазоне от 10 до 40 и `значение3` в диапазоне от 45 до 70 , значений будет до миллиарда, читал про некоторые `key-value`, но их сейчас появилось столько что все охватить сложно, конечно важна стабильность.

ps: работа идёт через Node.JS

Comment: Кроме aerospike, у которого может быть местами ограниченный aql, вспоминается http://memsql.com, у которого должна быть полная поддержка sql; есть еще ElasticSearch, который, возможно, опередит по скорости выборки всех остальных. Еще, насколько помню, у couchbase есть возможность организовать хранение полностью in-memory.

Comment: Спасибо , про aerospike и ElasticSearch не слышал, почитаю что они могут

Comment: Вобщем остановился на ElasticSearch ,Etki перенеси из комента в ответы чтобы я мог поставить "галочку"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш миллиард значений умещается в памяти, то воспользуйтесь Aerospike(для работы с этим вариантом вам нужен неразмеченный ssd)

Если у вас нет ssd, то можете воспользоваться Redis, только помните, это вариант не дает гарантий по сохранности данных, но предоставляет высокую производительность.

Я же рекомендовал бы использовать кассандру. Эта бд позволяет обработать 2к запросов в секунду на узел.

Comment: Aerospike интересен но он платный, бесплатная версия достаточно сильно ограниченна, а так идея хорошая. Пока что понравился ElasticSearch , но ещё подробнее тему кассандры помучаю, как я понял они по сути очень близки

Comment: @vnn198 Aerospike бесплатный, это премиум (с фишками вроде междатацентровой репликации) платный. Бесплатная версия сохраняет весь основной функционал. Cassandra и ElasticSearch - очень разные штуки, первое - структурированная распределенная база данных, второе - скорее неструктурированный поисковый движок.

Comment: ну я имел ввиду что и Cassandra и ElasticSearch построены как обёртки для Lucene, в принципе Lucene интересен, про ES почитал, теперь займусь Cassandra , может она не хуже, а может даже и лучше

Comment: @vnn198 насколько понимаю, кассандра не имеет ничего общего с люценом, разве что плагин для построения индексов. У них действительно просто разные задачи, одно - база данных, другое - поисковый движок (хотя в условиях стабильной сети данные можно хранить-обрабатывать и там, и там).

Comment: ну да, кассандра  не на лукене, просто сейчас про кучу разных бд читаю, вот уже смешалось всё :) кассандра интересна но её CQL немного отталкивает, ElasticSearch нравится его JSON'ом , я просто не очень "дружу" с SQL поэтому JSON мне как-то роднее, да и как я понял кассандру не так просто "кластеризовать", ElasticSearch прям подкупает своей простотой, хотя единственное что пока от него отталкивает, это непонятки с лицензией, как бы оно внезапно не стало платным, и в этом аспекте кассандра конечно интереснее выглядит

Comment: @vnn198 на сколько мне известно, проблема с кластеризацией проблем нет и даже наоборот. Во всяком случае ряд компаний, которые имеют дело с хайлоадом юзают именно кассандру и они довольны. Только замечу, там есть некоторые свои особенности, нельзя просто так взять, и начать юзать касандру как just another sql db

Comment: "нельзя просто так взять, и начать юзать касандру" вот это-то и пугает, ElasticSearch в этом плане девелопер-френдли :) . Ну почитаю ещё про кассандру , может не всё так страшно, по крайне мере инфы по кассандре в разы больше чем по ES

Comment: @vnn198 нет, просто взять и начать юзать кассандру конечно можно, но потом у вас будет высокий wtf per second. По этому сначала таки стоит почитать доку.